# Oracle SQL Error : Unable to execute Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute below Oracle SQL query

```
select m.*, n.region_building_count from 
(SELECT
  a.BUILDING_ID as "Building Id",
  d.Building_name as "Building Name",
  d.ADDRESS as "Building Address",
  d.REGION as "Region",
  d.Country as "Country",
  d.State as "State",
  d.City as "City"
FROM Company a, LOCATION d
where 1=1
and a.Building_ID like 'BLD-%') m
left JOIN
(select count(building_id) region_building_count, region
 from LOCATION l 
 where l.Building_ID like 'BLD-%' group by region) n
on m.region = n.region
```

But keep getting error like

```
Oracle database error 904: ORA-00904: "M"."REGION": invalid identifier
```

Any idea what I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use double-quotes when you define an alias like `"Region"` (which you should **never** do!), the alias becomes case-sensitive. When you reference `m.region`, that is not in double-quotes, the column name is automatically converted to upper-case `REGION`, which does not match `Region`.

Just don't use double-quotes around the aliases in the query and this problem will be cured. I didn't check the rest of the query to see if you will run into additional errors.

Alternatively, you could use `m."Region"` everywhere (in double quotes). Bad practice!